# Присоединение приставки к местоимению при помощи дефиса

Tags: орфография, местоимения, дефис, приставка, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Скажите, как оформлять соединение приставки и местоимения, через дефис? Что это за правило, где его прочитать? "Недо-я", "псевдо-мы", "анти-он"?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамота.ру" в итоге ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309616)).

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Специального правила о написании приставок с личными местоимениями
> пока нет. В академическом орфографическом словаре зафиксировано два
> слова такой модели: *не-я* и *сверх-я*. По образцу этих слов можно писать и другие подобные.

Comment: Есть ли примеры соединения приставки и местоимения?

Comment: "Грамота.ру" сказала, что есть: "сверх-я" и "не-я" как минимум.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Нет такого правила, и прочитать его негде.** https://orfo.ruslang.ru/search/word

Но есть грамматика и правила образования слов и словосочетаний. Есть три возможных способов письма (слитно, раздельно, дефис).

Берете любое, например ***псевдо-мы***. К личному местоимению нельзя присоединить приставку, слитное написание невозможно.

Раздельное написание такого вида в русском языке не применяется.

Остается дефис по методу исключения. Фактически это сложное слово с дефисным написанием форманта ***псевдо***-, которое с существительными пишется обычно слитно (псевдогерой), но здесь особый случай.

**Орфографический словарь**

псевдо… – первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно (перед прописной буквой и дефисно пишущимся словом – через дефис)

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=псевдо&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE&all=x)