# Пол-тебя, пол-её

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Я знаю все правила, которые говорят об использовании *пол-* и *полу-* с разными словами, но там нет ни единого правила, которое бы мне подсказало, как *пол-* и *полу-* писать с местоимениями. В этой связи можете, пожалуйста, мне подсказать, как в данной-то ситуации быть-таки? Я предполагаю,  что нужен дефис таки, например: *полу-я, пол-меня, полу-она, пол-её, полу-он, пол-его, полу-мы.*

Comment: Полу всегда вместе вроде? Полупол полумы полупомыли.

Comment: @Pumpkin 777, быть может, вам пригодится ответ на вопрос, где речь идёт о присоединении приставок к местоимениям: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470944/

Comment: @ShiKomarishe ну смотрите есть слово причём), чём - местоимение. есть сложные слова с местоимениями сам и вы - самосвал выехал. А приставки по ссылке все отрицают само местоимение псевдо-я - не-я.