# Недо-вас/недовас

Tags: орфография, местоимения, дефис, приставка, слитно-дефис

Как правильно?

1. Я, когда на улице был, повстречал какую-то недо-вас.
2. Я, когда на улице был, повстречал какую-то недовас.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобный вопрос уже задавался: [Присоединение приставки к местоимению при помощи дефиса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470944/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0).

Ответ на него дала и "Грамота.ру" (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309616)), обозначив возможность дефисного написания в таких случаях.

**Вопрос № 309616**

> Скажите, как оформлять соединение приставки и личного местоимения,
> через дефис? Что это за правило, где его прочитать? "Недо-я",
> "псевдо-мы", "анти-он"?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Специального правила о написании приставок с личными местоимениями
> пока нет. В академическом орфографическом словаре зафиксировано два
> слова такой модели: *не-я* и *сверх-я*. По образцу этих слов можно писать
> и другие подобные.

Получается, по аналогии верен 1-й вариант.

*Я, когда на улице был, повстречал какую-то **недо-вас**.*